# Last 12 months, group by week

Tags: group-by

I have a table with a column REGDATE, a registration date (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). I would like to show an histogram (ExtJS) in order to understand in which period of the years users are signing up. I would like to do this for the past twelve months with respect to the current date and to group dates by week.

Any hints?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE_FORMAT(regdate, "%X%V") AS regweek FROM table GROUP BY regweek;
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*), YEARWEEK(NOW(), 2) as regweek FROM table GROUP BY regweek;
```

in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM regdate)::text ||  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM regdate)::text AS regweek FROM table GROUP BY regweek;
```

Comment: I tried the PostgreSQL and got an error.  Had to add ::varchar after EXTRACT(YEAR).

Comment: For those looking for a PostgreSQL version, Tom Gerken's  example below  is better. It limits to 12 months, zero pads the dates, and handles datetime to text conversion.

Answer (score 30):

FWIW in PostgreSQL, Karaszi has an answer that works, but there is a faster query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', REGDATE) AS "Week" , count(*) AS "No. of users"
FROM <<TABLE>>
WHERE REGDATE > now() - interval '12 months' 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I based this off the work of [Ben Goodacre](http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Group_by_day,_week_or_month_%28PostgreSQL%29)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
select to_char(REGDATE,'WW') "Week number",
       count(*) "number of signups",
from YOUR_TABLE
where REGDATE > current_date-365
group by to_char(REGDATE,'WW')
order by to_char(REGDATE,'WW')
```

Comment: +1 for use of `TO_CHAR`. I wanted unique week (rather than periodic by year) so I used `to_char(regdate, 'YYYY WW')`, but same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (SQL)

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), REGDATE, 120) AS [RegistrationMonth]
FROM ...
GROUP BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), REGDATE, 120)
ORDER BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), REGDATE, 120)
```